# Wordpress meta value empty no display

Tags: wordpress, post

I am using a directory theme and I am using the following code:

```
<?php $listing_contact = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'listing_contact', true ); echo $listing_contact; ?>
<?php if( empty( $listing_contact) ) : ?>no contact<?php endif; ?>
```

However, the 'no contact' value is not displaying once the `$listing_contact` is empty. Can somebody help me out to get this working?

Comment: @festinger...your code should work..nothing wrong init...check get_the_id() when you don't get proper result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, even though I would advise you to rewrite it:

```
<?php $listing_contact = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'listing_contact', true ); ?> 

<?php if ( empty( $listing_contact ) ) : ?>
   No contact
<?php else : ?>
   <?php echo $listing_contact;
<?php endif; ?>
```

Maybe check that you get the right ID in `get_the_ID()` or that your actually looking for `empty()` in your conditional.

Answer (score 0):

The below will check and see if `$listing_contact` has any value if it doesn't display anything if it does display the contents of `$listing_contact`.

```
<?php
$listing_contact = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'listing_contact', true ); 
if(!($listing_contact == null || $listing_contact == '')){
    echo $listing_contact; 
}else{
    echo "no contact";
}
?>
```

Would you please try above code?